# numpy find last less than value index in sorted array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a exactly sorted numpy array like this:

```
arr = np.asarray([1351.1, 1351.11, 1351.14, 1351.16])
```

and I have a value array also exactly sorted value like this:

```
vs = np.asarray([1351.10, 1351.13, 1351.17])
```

I want to find the last index of value in `arr` is less than or equal to `vs`, for example:

1. `vs[0]=1351.10` => `arr[0] == v[0]` => output `0`
2. `vs[1]=1351.13` => `arr[1] < v[1]` and `arr[2] > v[1]` => output `1`
3. `vs[2]=1351.17` => `arr[3] < v[2]` => output `3`

so at last output `[0, 1, 3]`

Of course I can for loop `arr`, then compare `arr` with `vs`, but if `arr` size is very big, it maybe not a good option.

And I find `np.searchsorted`, it is not what my want, for example:
`np.searchsorted(arr, 1351.13)` returns `2`, but I want to `1`. And also another question, it cannot make use of `vs` is also sorted.

Comment: Can't you do something like this `print([np.searchsorted(arr, x, side='right')-1 for x in vs])`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `np.searchsorted` with `side = 'right'` and then subtract 1:

```
np.searchsorted(arr, vs, side = 'right') - 1

array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
```